# How I can know if the user cancel the subscription from google play store using in_app_purchase Flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

In internal testing if I make a subscription and then unsubscribe it from the play store the product is still showing purchased. I want to know, how can I check if the user unsubscribe the product from play store ?

This is the initialization function

```
  Future initiazlize() async {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = _iap.purchaseStream;

    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) async {
      _purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);

      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
      notifyListeners();
    },
    availble = await _iap.isAvailable();
    notifyListeners();
    if (availble == true) {
      print("Is store availble ${availble}");
      await _getProducts();
    }
  }
```

this is the buy subscription function

```
  buySubscription(String id) async{
    PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
        productDetails: _products.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id));
    try {
      await _iap.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error while buying ${e}');
    }
  }
```

This is the purchase Update function

```
  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.pending:

        //  _showPendingUI();
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
          if (purchaseDetails.productID == subscriptionId) {
            setPurchases(fASubscribed: true);
          }

          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.restored:
          if (purchaseDetails.productID == subscriptionId) {
            setPurchases(fASubscribed: true);
          }

          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
          print(purchaseDetails.error);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await _iap.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    });
  }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine if the person unsubscribes just by using your mobile app with the connection to the store. As far as I know, whenever a purchase is made, you need to store the purchased item in your database, and you have to call the `completePurchase` function in the mobile app after verifying the purchase with the Play Store/App Store in your server. Regarding your question on how to detect when a user unsubscribes from a purchase, you have to connect your backend server to the Play Store using Firebase, and you also need to configure webhooks in the case of the App Store. End-to-end in-app purchase configuration is explained in this guide, check it out here: [flutter-in-app-purchases](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases)

Comment: when a user cancels a subscription, this should work 
**case PurchaseStatus.canceled:**
          **print('cancelled product ${purchaseDetails.productID}');**
         ** if (purchaseDetails.productID == subscriptionId) {**
              **setPurchases(**
               ** fASubscribed: false,**
             ** );**
         ** }**
          **break;**